# error while loading shared libraries: bdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, shared-library

I  installed TeamTalk from http://bearwear.dk inside my home directory, but when I try to run  `./tt5srv -wizard` I get

```
error while loading shared libraries: bdl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried with and without `sudo`

I found fixes for other libraries but I didn't see any mention of bdl.so.2.

Ubuntu 18.04. How to fix this? Is it another case of wrong location or symlink?

Comment: I appreciate the edits. I couldn't type it better.

Answer (score 0):

Before running TeamTalk, you'll need to install some dependencies.

you can install it by typing

```
sudo apt install libqt5x11extras5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 \
libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5quick5 libqt5widgets5 \
libqt5multimedia5 libqt5gui5 libqt5webchannel5 \
libqt5qml5 libqt5network5 libqt5xml5 libqt5core5a libasound2
```

in terminal.

**Source:** README file in TeamTalk

Comment: I edited my post for the correct software.

Comment: Did you try this answer?

Comment: Yes. I copy-pasted everything but the error persists. I'll check again.

Comment: are you running by `./run.sh` ?

Comment: run.sh? I run ./tt5srv -wizard. I am expecting the program to display a wizard to setup a configuration file. On CentOS I had almost similar issue but it was looking for libssl.so.10 which I was able to solve. But this bdl.so.2 is new to me.

Comment: you are using this package http://bearware.dk/teamtalk/v5.5/teamtalk-v5.5-ubuntu18-x86_64.tgz?  no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110643/discussion-between-kashish-and-joey).

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.